# CoCreateInstance - What is the reverse?

Tags: c++, c, com

Using COM you use [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create an object.

Is there a way of destroying it totally so the next part of the unit test can start from afresh?

Comment: Are you looking for [IUnknown::Release()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317.aspx)?

Comment: But how to guarantee that the destructor is called for the implementation?

Comment: See also: [Do you know when your destructors run? Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/20/135841.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/21/136701.aspx).

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to test the wrong things anyway. Why is it important to the test that it receive a fresh object? If it's *really* important, then *don't* release the previous object. Instead, keep it, and in the next test, check that the next object you allocate is indeed distinct from the previous one. (You can only check that if you haven't already released the first one.)

Comment: @RobKennedy - Every test should be independent. From a fresh slate.So I am testing a COM object that is a singleton. What to start again from scratch but it is not calling the destructor.  Trying to figure of why

Comment: If it's really a singleton, then the COM server should ensure that the object never gets destroyed. It will check whether it's created an object before, and of it has, it will continue returning what it believes to be that object, even if it's been destroyed through other means. You could run each test in a separate process. Or you could just use your setup function to put the singleton into a known state prior to each test.

Comment: It is a COM object and unregistered. It is in process. Can I just destroy it and move on and start the process as nothing has happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone holding a referenced COM interface pointer is guaranteed that the object is alive, so without knowing everyone who holds interface pointers to your COM object, and being able to ask to release you cannot make sure the object is destroyed.

You certainly can try

```
for(; ; )
{
  if(pFoo->Release() == 0)
    break;
}
```

However even with this you (a) can get dead loop, (b) those referencing your object will get access violation/undefined behavior once they try to access destroyed object (they still expect the referenced object to be alive).

Another approach is that you use a wrapper object and manage the real COM object internally without exposing it. And you forward methods calls from wrapper to inner object. Then you can ask your wrapper to release the internal references and this typically leads to destruction of the inner object.

Comment: How can one find out what is holding onto the COM object in VS 2010?

Comment: There is no way, this part is lightweight. COM object does not see/know who is using it exactly. It only manages a reference counter so that it knows when it is no longer use and it is time to self-destroy.

Comment: SO debugging is difficult. As I want to create (setUp) and destroy (tearDown) objects for testing but not sure why they are not calling the destructor. And tips to find out who is not playing ball?.

Comment: In most cases you will be happy with releasing all pointers you hold. For most of the COM objects you can still check `IUnknown::Release` returned value and compare it against zero to make sure that your final release is actual destruction. If you are okay to make it more complicated on client (unit test) side and raise chances that actual destruction takes place - start a child process and do unit test stuff there. Terminating process you also terminate references from various worker threads, related to marshaling, related to reference leaks etc.

Comment: Going more complicated on COM server object side, you can log/save call stack using debug API (`StackWalk` and friends) every time you get `IUnknown::AddRef`, `IUnknown::Release` calls. Having that you can track back the history of calls and get at least some idea about leaky references. If COM server is built using ATL, you can also utilize [`_ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycfy8ec) and [`_ATL_DEBUG_QI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7067t4w6).

Comment: Note that the value returned by IUnknown::Release can not be relied upon  to the the real reference count. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx .  For example: Proxy objects do not need to return the real reference count, just the reference count of the proxy object.

Comment: If I put it in process. What debugging techniques to find out what is holding onto the reference (BTW I can make it unregistered)

Comment: @RichardCritten: comparing to zero is more relaxed requirement than getting real counter value, however you are correct here and your comment falls under "you can get dead loop" above.

Comment: @EdHeal Put a break point on the object creation and look at the stack frame to see who / what is creating it.

Comment: @EdHeal: It is unreal to realibly find references using process dump. There are two things you can realistically do: (1) inspect your own object which can hold those references, (2) log AddRef/Release calls as I mentioned above to have a history of reference changes. When you take a snapshot of process, COM pointer reference there is just a pointer sized value somewhere - finding it blindly and reversing to "who is its owner" is not what you want (or even can) do.

Comment: .. But it is a shared pointer - so who has a copy and how do I find the villian

Comment: If there is a bug related to bad reference counting you can even get scenario when entire process has no pointer - it's gone completely. And reference counter is still non-zero and destruction never happens.